# RS command not found

Tags: bash, command

I am doing a research on a number of subjects which requires that I submit my script to a supercomputer. My script was working fine on the individual subject, but I am getting this error when i submit it to the supercomputer.

rs command not found.

I am new to scripting but when i looked for this command in my terminal (type rs) it existed- but when i did the same in the supercomputer shell rs was not there.

Is there a way to download this specific command ?
THank you

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you provide more information about the systems involved ? which rs command are we talking about ? rs.exe from microsoft sql server? And do you know what kind of system is running on your supercomputer?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am using the bash terminal and the RS command is used to reshape a data array. The supercomputer runs on CentOS-7.4 Linux

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your script does not include the details of `$PATH` variable when it gets executed.

To resolve this find the location of `rs` using `which rs` and include that location in the `$PATH` variable and export it inside the script. It would look something like this in your script:

```
export PATH=$PATH:`which rs`
```

`NOTE:` This might not work and you might have to replace the location of `rs` command explicitly instead of using it in a single command.

`PS.` Assuming you have `rs` extension installed in your system.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems that Cent0S doesnt have the rs extension. As compared to my OSX . How do I download this extension? 
https://github.com/chneukirchen/rs
I have found the above link yet i dont know how to download the extension from it to the supercomputer. What link should i use. 

THank you

Comment: *How do I download this extension?*. I'd really be surprised if a supercomputing environment would allow installation of software without going through an extensive validation. That is a question that can only be answered by the local gurus or system admins. A good excuse to leave you desk and meet some new people in your organization ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: If you have a root user account you can use `sudo apt install rs` to install the extension.